# Custom edit user page

Tags: hooks, users, forms

I'm trying to build an edit form for specific users. 
**For one type of user I want to hide password field for example**

What I did is to create a module called `profilechange`.

Into `profilechange.module` I wrote this code :

```
function profilechange_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user-profile-form') {
       hide($form['account']['pass']);
       hide($form['account']['current_pass_required_values']);
       hide($form['account']['current_pass']);
    }
}
```

So I enable the module and into my `page--user--edit.tpl.php` I've this code :

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

It displays the default edit form. But password fields are not hidden.

That's why I need your help, I don't know why it does not work even if I clear the cache

Comment: try with unset() function

Comment: Notice that the correct form id should be `user_profile_form` in the `if` statement. Use low hyphens to refer to machine names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also might try the [user readonly module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_readonly). It allows to disable or hide certain form fields for certain users.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this...

```
$form['account']['pass']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

- If you're altering a form HOOK_form_alter() you set #access to FALSE.
- If you're on the theme layer (theme function or file), you can use hide().

The '#access' property means the element is not rendered and the user submitted value is not taken into consideration
See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access

The hide() function hides an element from rendering later in the process.
See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/hide/7